# Trouble querying the correct info from gv$encryption_wallet

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, sqlplus

I'm trying to get the wallet status for the current instance of an Oracle 11g 2 node RAC DB (but ideally all RDBMS versions). The following command returns values for both nodes instead of one:

```
SQL> select a.status from gv$encryption_wallet a, gv$instance b where a.INST_ID=(select INST_ID from gv$instance where instance_number=userenv('instance')) and a.WRL_TYPE='HSM';

STATUS
------------------------------
OPEN
OPEN
```

If I break it down it doesn't show the info for node 2 .. only node 1. And I'm running the cmd from node 2.

```
SQL> select INST_ID from gv$instance where instance_number=userenv('instance');

   INST_ID
----------
         2

SQL> select a.status from gv$encryption_wallet a, gv$instance b where a.INST_ID=2 and a.WRL_TYPE='HSM';

no rows selected
```

It's problem something really obvious but I just can't see it at the moment. Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the values of the current instance where you are connected to, just query the v$ views instead of the gv$ view, that lists the values of the complete instance group where you are connected to.

Comment: Yes that works too ... I don't understand why the result above returns no records but as you pointed out it's not necessary. Many thanks.